# How do 2 users on ansible node connect to thesame worker node

Tags: ansible, connection, users, remote

I set up 2 new users with their respective key pairs,.. their public keys ve been established on the remote host. The problem am having is I passsed the ssh keys on the host file as follows

[remotehost:var]
ansible_ssh_private_key_file=~/.ssh/user1.private_key
ansible_ssh_private_key_file=~/.ssh/user2.private_key

The problem is only one user could establish ansible connection. Even tho both users can ssh into the remote host.

Am sure there’s a way set both users up to reach thesame node in the host file

Answer (score 0):

When the users are different on the node running Ansible, you might drop the user name from the base name of the file:  `~/.ssh/remotehost.private_key`    The path is passed to ssh, and `~` is resolved to their personal home directory.

When same local user needs to connect to multiple different remote users, can make "fake" hosts in inventory with different [connection vars](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_inventory.html#connecting-to-hosts-behavioral-inventory-parameters). ini format:

```
[remotehost]
remotehostuser1 ansible_user=user1 ansible_ssh_private_key_file=~/.ssh/user1.private_key
remotehostuser2 ansible_user=user2 ansible_ssh_private_key_file=~/.ssh/user2.private_key


[remotehost:vars]
ansible_host=remotehost
```

More ways to do this exist. Making use of the environment var way of providing a private_key_file, `${ANSIBLE_PRIVATE_KEY_FILE}` Or using ssh_config.